# How to access JOptionPane commands in showInputDialog?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Here is my code:

```
public static void nameset(){
    int no = 1;
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "The last people who still had cake had to defend it with heir lives, No matter the cost.\nOne of those last people, was you. What is your name?", "",1);     
    if(name.equals("") || name.equals(JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION));{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Please tell me your name. I don't wanna have to exit out of the game about you.","Hey!",1);
        no++;
    }if (name.equals("") || name.equals(JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)){
        if (no == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Seriously? Again?! that's it..");
            if (name.equals(JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)){
                System.exit(0);
            }else{
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want it so if you press the cancel option it tell you to restart. But if you press cancel, it shows an error in the console. I think it's the `name.equals(JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)`, But I'm not sure. Is there any reason for it not to work? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: *"But if you press cancel, it shows an error in the console."*  By 'console' DYM the command line interface?  What use is that to the user?

Answer (score 0):

The cancel button will always result in `null` being returned. See [official JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
Returns:    user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input
```

So your condition should be changed to:

```
if(name == null || name.equals(""))
```

and you also need to remove the semicolon after your first `if` statement! Otherwise the following block will always be executed.

Once that's fixed, your "exit after 3 times no" will not work because you're not actually looping your input dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   int no = 1;
   String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The last people who still had cake had to defend it with heir lives, No matter the cost.\nOne of those last people, was you. What is your name?", "",1);     
    if(name == null || name.equals(""));{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please tell me your name. I don't wanna have to exit out of the game about you.","Hey!",1);
        no++;
    }if (name == null || name.equals("")){
        if (no == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seriously? Again?! that's it.."+name);
            if (name == null || name.equals("")){
                System.exit(0);
            }else{
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```